# Prefixing IDs from hamls bracket notation to prevent repetition of the same ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using partials for single objects like so:

```
#/app/views/people/_person.html.haml
%div[person]
  = image_tag person.image
  %p.name= person.full_name
  %p.location= person.location
```

... so I can use the `render` method for groups of objects like so:

```
#/app/views/people/index.html.haml
%ul.people
  - @people.each do |person|
    %li= render person
```

But then, if I render an object more than once, i get two elements with the same id, which is not so good, if only for the sake of validating. Is there a way to keep the above single object partial and then later, when calling render, tell it to prefix the id or something, to keep the ids unique?

Let's take an example. Say, I have a facebook clone of sorts. In the sidebar I have a list of people you might find interesting, at the main area I have a list of all my friends (I am currently in the people index view) and at the header I have a list of people, who lately tried to contact me. These three sets might share some of the same people, so I would get multiple elements with the same id. Instead of giving them all the id `person_654`, as haml would do with the bracket notation, I would like to give the person in the sidebar the id `interesting_person_654`, the person in the header the id `lately_calling_person_654` and the person in the main area (the person from the current view) the id `person_654`.

How would I do that?

I thought of using some option for namespace, but the render method only has 4 options and namespace is not one of them. I would be fine with monkeypatching the render method, though. I would rather not obscure the objects partial with id-prefixing logic (which I would even have to copy-paste in every other object partial -- not good at all!).

Comment: Have you considered using `classes` instead. And to identify them use the `data` tag. iE: "data-person-id='12'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution:

When passing a record in the brackets, haml uses the records `haml_object_ref` method to determine, what values to use for the class and the id prefix. Thus, I rewrote the rendering helper, so that it can adjust this methhod accordingsly before rendering:

```
# config/initializers/extensions/action_view_extension.rb
#
# (For some reason that is beyond be I could override this method in
# ActionView::Helpers::RenderingHelper, so for not I patched it at class level)
#
class ActionView::Base

  alias_method :original_render, :render

  def render objects = [], options = {}, *args, &block
    class_prefix = options[:class_prefix] || options[:namespace] || options[:as]
    records = Array( objects ).select { |object| object.is_a? ActiveRecord::Base }
    records.each do |record|
      class_name = record.class.to_s.underscore
      record.define_singleton_method :haml_object_ref do
        [class_prefix, class_name].compact.join( '_' )
      end
    end

    original_render objects, options, *args, &block

  end
end
```

Now i can call `render` in a view like this:

```haml
#header
  %ul.lately_calling_people
    %li = render @lately_calling_people[0], as: 'lately_calling'
    %li = render @lately_calling_people[1], as: 'lately_calling'
    %li = render @lately_calling_people[2], as: 'lately_calling'

#sidebar
  %ul.interesting_people
    %li= render @interesting_people[0], as: 'interesting'
    %li= render @interesting_people[1], as: 'interesting'
    %li= render @interesting_people[2], as: 'interesting'

#main
  %div[@person]
    @person.name
    ...
```

Which will produce the following html:

```html
...

<ul class="lately_calling_people"
  <li><div class="lately_calling_person" id="lately_calling_person_1">...</div></li>
  ...
</ul>

...

<ul class="interesting_people"
  <li><div class="interesting_person" id="interesting_person_1">...</div></li>
  ...
</ul>

...

<div class="person" id="person_1">
  ...
</div>
```

And I can keep the partial simple:

```haml
# app/views/people/_person.html.haml
%div[person]
  = image_tag person.image
  %p.name= person.full_name
  %p.location= person.location
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs the Haml’s object reference syntax](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#object_reference_):

> Additionally, the second argument (if present) will be used as a prefix for both the id and class attributes.

So you can just change:

```
%div[person]
```

to (for example):

```
%div[person, :interesting]
```

which will generate something like:

```
<div class='interesting_person' id='interesting_person_7'>...
```

Then later:

```
%div[person, :lately_calling]
```

will create:

```
<div class='lately_calling_person' id='lately_calling_person_7'>
```

Comment: Well, I knew that, but how does it solve my problem? Now every person would have the ID `lately_calling_person_7`.